# What is the best way to make this SQL query as Elequent statement

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I need following sql statement to translate to the Laravel Eloquent.  tried several ways and literally failed.

```
SELECT * FROM `conversations` where `type` = 'open' 
AND `sender_id`=2 AND ((`deleted_by_sender` IS NULL ) 
AND (`deleted_by_sender` IS NULL  OR `deleted_by_receiver` IS NULL  )) 
OR `receiver_id` = 2 AND ((`deleted_by_sender` IS NULL ) 
AND (`deleted_by_sender` IS NULL  OR `deleted_by_receiver` IS NULL  ))
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can perform you query in eloquent in this way, i assumed you have a model called Conversation

```
Conversation::where('type', 'open')
->where('sender_id', 2)
->whereNull('deleted_by_sender')
->where(function ($query) {
    return $query->whereNull('deleted_by_sender')
        ->orWhereNull('deleted_by_receiver');
})->orWhere('receiver_id', 2)
->whereNull('deleted_by_sender')
->where(function ($query) {
    return $query->whereNull('deleted_by_sender')
        ->orWhereNull('deleted_by_receiver');
})->get();
```

these code is untested, translated straight from your sql query

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you are expecting this:

```
SELECT * FROM `conversations` 
 WHERE `type` = 'open' 
   AND ( `deleted_by_sender` IS NULL OR `deleted_by_receiver` IS NULL )
   AND ( ( `sender_id`=2 AND `deleted_by_sender` IS NULL )
         OR
         ( `receiver_id` = 2 AND `deleted_by_receiver` IS NULL )
       )
```